# Black Ops for Mac on ATI Radeon HD 4670 256 MB

Tags: macos, call-of-duty-black-ops, graphics-card

I initially planned to purchase Black Ops for Mac from the Mac App Store for my late 2009 iMac.  I was thinking I'd then buy GameCompanion and connect an Xbox 360 controller to my computer, effectively making it an Xbox. Unfortunately, I just checked the machine's specs, only to find that I have 256 MB of video RAM instead of the recommended 512 MB.

The exact card is the ATI Radeon HD 4670 256 MB. If I did purchase the game, would I notice a severe amount of dropped frames, making gameplay really frustrating? If so, are there quality settings in the game I could turn down? Also, could the use of a wireless controller create additional lag? Any advice appreciated.

All machine specs are as follows:

[image]

Comment: There's a reason there are system requirements; if your computer doesn't meet them, you're going to experience performance issues.

Comment: I understand. Perhaps I could add to the question whether there are quality settings within the game that I could change that would improve the experience on slightly outdated hardware?

Comment: This is still pretty localized; I think it's on the edge of what is acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how relevant this is for you. I have a C2D E6550 and a Radeon 3850 and I can play Black Ops on Windows 7 with good framerate (above 45) on 1280 x 720.

The use of a good wireless controller is not going to create any noticeable lag. I would highly suggest that you go ahead and use keyboard mouse for playing a FPS on a PC.